# Example of non-zero functions with identically zero convolution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convolution

I want to find two functions $f_1, f_2 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which are not zero almost everywhere, but $f_1 * f_2$ is a zero function.

My first idea is to try function with disjoint support. So I choose two simple functions with disjoint compact supports $$f_1 = \chi_{[0,1]}, f_2 = \chi_{[2,3]}.$$ Then $$f_1 * f_2 (x) = \int_0^1 \chi_{[2,3]}(x-y) dy.$$ When $x$ is such that $x-y \in [0,1]$, the convolution wont be zero there.

Next I try a simple function with function that integrate to zero on a finite interval like $f(x) = x - 3$ on $[2,4]$ and zero outside. The convolution still not zero.

So I am not sure what type of functions I should looks for.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I’m not sure what the answer would be, but the Titchmarsh Lemma gives that they must have infinite support.

Comment: I don't have an explicit example but if $f= \hat {\phi},g= \hat {\psi}$ where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth even functions with compact support whose supports are disjoint then Fourier transform of  $f*g=0$ so $f*g=0$.

Comment: Smooth even function ? You mean $c^\infty$ with compact support with $f(-x) = f(x)$ ? Oh, I have never thought of them, and yeah I cannot think of one such functions.

Answer (score 5):

Kavi had the right idea, but smoothness is unnecessary. The functions
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) &=& \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \\
g(x) &=& \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cos(3x)
\end{eqnarray}
have Fourier transforms with finite and disjoint support, so their convolution vanishes identically.